# Error : forward declaration of ‘Display {aka struct _XDisplay}’ struct _XDisplay while using Xdo lib in Qt 5

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, header-files

I have a header file like this :
**xmousetrack.hpp**

```
#ifndef XMOUSETRACK_HPP
#define XMOUSETRACK_HPP

#include <QThread>

extern "C"
{
  #include <xdo.h>
}

class MouseTrack : public QThread
{
    Display * dpy;
    xdo_t * xdo;

public:
    int x, prev_x, y, Xheight;
    MouseTrack();
    ~MouseTrack();

public slots:
    void trackpointer();

signals:
    void toggleWin();

};


#endif // XMOUSETRACK_HP
```

**xmousetrack.cxx**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "mainwindow.hpp"
#include "xmousetrack.hpp"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    MouseTrack * mT = new MouseTrack;
    mT->moveToThread(&mouseThread);

    connect(&mouseThread, SIGNAL(finished()), mT, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(signalMouse()), mT, SLOT(trackPointer()));
    mouseThread.start();
}

void MainWindow::showWin()
{
    show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    mouseThread.requestInterruption();
    mouseThread.quit();
    mouseThread.wait();
}

MouseTrack::MouseTrack()
{
    xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (!dpy)
    {
        std::cerr << "XOpenDisplay(0x0) returned 0x0" << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Xheight = HeightOfScreen(dpy);
    Xheight -= (Xheight - 20); //the last 20 height in pixels of the screen
}

MouseTrack::~MouseTrack()
{
    xdo_free(xdo);
}

void MouseTrack::trackpointer() //slot function
{
    xdo_get_mouse_location(xdo, &x , &y , CURRENTWINDOW);
    prev_x = x;

    while(!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
    {
        qDebug("x=%d y=%d", x,y);
        QThread::usleep(1000);
        xdo_get_mouse_location(xdo, &x , &y , CURRENTWINDOW);
        if ( abs(x - prev_x) > 10 and y >= Xheight)
        {
            qDebug("Showing window...");
        }
        prev_x = x;
    }
}
```

`
The error message:

`Invalid use of incomplete type 'Display {aka struct_xDisplay}`
`forward declaration of 'Display {aka struct_xDisplay}`

I think both the Qt and the xdo.h header files contains the display structure. I'm not using Qtx11info.h as it doesn't fulfill my task when the app is hidden in background. The only library flag I'm using is `-lxdo` in the .pro file.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], your code is not complete because the content of xmousetrack.cxx is missing

Comment: @eyllanesc edited.

Comment: A guess is that someone forward declares `struct Display;` and someone else does `typedef struct _XDisplay Display;`. And that's a conflict.

Comment: @BoPersson `xlib.h` forward declares the `struct _XDisplay` and the code in `xlib.h` is as follows (though I am not including xlib.h):  

`struct _XDisplay;  /* Forward declare before use for C++ */

typedef struct {
.
.
.
} Screen;`

Comment: @BoPersson Yes you are correct. I just checked xlib.h file. Now what should I do?

Comment: @xcfg96 - If possible, you can hide the include in a cpp file so the conflicting headers don't meet. Otherwise you have a problem.  :-(  C++ invented namespaces for this, but that doesn't help C code.

Comment: @BoPersson My code works fine as standalone but when using it with Qt, it is giving me this error. I'm not getting what to do? May you please write an answer so that I can accept it and it can work?

Comment: @xcfg96 - Sorry, I don't know Qt or X well enough to tell how to mix them. Or why you would like to use both. Surely Qt also has mouse handlers. Perhaps you could use those?

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks. I am using the xlib mouse functions and the Qt display one.